# Move checkbox and text to left or right on click of a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am pretty new to wpf. I have 5 checkboxes each with its color picker and text.
I want to select a checkbox and then click **<** or **>** button to move the checkboxes left or right along with text and its color picker.

```
<CheckBox Content="Channel 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,50,0,33" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="292,50,0,35" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="668,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="541,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="422,51,0,33" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"/>
    <Button Content="&lt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,44,0,31" Width="27" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
    <Button Content="&gt;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="795,44,0,31" Width="27" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>

    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="117,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="369,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="497,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="616,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
    <c1:C1ColorPicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="743,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="19"/>
```

for example if the checkboxes are aligned as

Channel 1  Channel 2 Channel 3 Channel 4 Channel 5
and i checked channel 3 and clicked **<** button then the new order will be 
Channel 1  Channel 3 Channel 2 Channel 4 Channel 5

edited:

local namespace added as : `xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"`

custom control EnhancedCheckBoxControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class EnhancedCheckBoxControl : CheckBox
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There are many improvements possible e.g. create a own control which contains a `CheckBox` and a `ColorPicker` the same goes for the usage of the `margin` instead use a `Grid` or a `ListView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented some little improvement (removed `margin` added custom control), there is much more which could be improved.

Your XAML file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl">
                    <ContentControl>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <c1:C1ColorPicker Width="39" Height="19"/>
                        </StackPanel >
                    </ContentControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="spToSort" Grid.Column="1">
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 1" />
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 2" />
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 3" />
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 4" />
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 5" />
        <local:EnhancedCheckBoxControl Content="Channel 6" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Button Content="&lt;" Grid.Column="0" Width="27" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Click="Button_Left"/>
    <Button Content="&gt;" Grid.Column="2" Width="27" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Click="Button_Right"/>
</Grid>
```

The code behind for moving:

```
private IEnumerable<EnhancedCheckBoxControl> GetStackPanelsToMove()
{
    return spToSort.Children.OfType<EnhancedCheckBoxControl>()
        .Where(cb => cb.IsChecked.HasValue && cb.IsChecked.Value);
}

private void Button_Left(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<EnhancedCheckBoxControl> stackPanelsToMove = GetStackPanelsToMove()
        .OrderBy(sp => spToSort.Children.IndexOf(sp));

    foreach (var spToMove in stackPanelsToMove) {
        int position = spToSort.Children.IndexOf(spToMove);
        if (position <= 0) { continue; }

        spToSort.Children.Remove(spToMove);
        spToSort.Children.Insert(position - 1, spToMove);
    }
}

private void Button_Right(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<EnhancedCheckBoxControl> stackPanelsToMove = GetStackPanelsToMove()
        .OrderByDescending(sp => spToSort.Children.IndexOf(sp));

    foreach (var spToMove in stackPanelsToMove)
    {
        int position = spToSort.Children.IndexOf(spToMove);
        if (position >= spToSort.Children.Count - 1) { continue; }

        spToSort.Children.Remove(spToMove);
        spToSort.Children.Insert(position + 1, spToMove);
    }
}
```

The custom control is a empty class which inherits from `CheckBox`:

```
public class EnhancedCheckBoxControl : CheckBox
{
}
```

Comment: I tried this but giving errors like namespace prefix local is not defined and EnhancedCheckboxControl is not supported.

Comment: The `local` namespace is the namespace where the `EnhancedCheckbpxControl` belongs to. You have to add it at the top in your Window where the other Namespaces are defined.

Comment: I am still getting Error :
The name "EnhancedCheckBoxControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication3". Please help

Comment: @PSDebugger in the xaml at the top there is some kind of namespace declaration like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"` and now you have to move the namespace of your `EnhancedCheckBoxControl` to the same like `namespace WpfApplication3 { ...`

Comment: There is also another possibility: you can add a new namespace declaration for the `EnhancedCheckBox` namespace.

Comment: I have added the code for the EnhancedCheckBox custom control. It is same as you mentioned still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have your `EnhancedCheckBox` in the root of your project and the  namespace is set correct?

Comment: yes it is the in the project and i think the namespace is set correct as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116620/discussion-between-kevin-wallis-and-psdebugger).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is achievable very easily by placing the controls in a grid and moving them dynamically. Divide your main grid into 5 columns first. Each column consisting of a CheckBox. Now when each checkbox is checked or unchecked, you could catch the event and identify the selected checkbox. When user clicks on **<** button, change the column of the checkbox and its alternate checkbox using below code :

You can call SetValue on the object for which you want change the grid column value:

```
Checkbox3.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
mainGrid.Children.Add(Checkbox3);
Checkbox2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 3);
mainGrid.Children.Add(Checkbox2);
```

Assuming that you’re trying to move the 3rd checkbox to the left.